# Hardware acceleration on Honeycomb: can you take advantage of hardware acceleration when drawing to an offscreen bitmap?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb

on Android 3.0 when android:hardwareAccelerated=true, is it possible to take advantage of the hardwareAcceleration when drawing to a offscreen Bitmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as far as I experienced, hardware acceleration is applied just while painting on actual screen.